# Android Webview troubled interaction with Dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am having a lot of trouble communicating between the webview and dynamic content. I am unable to capture Urls using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method and now I am unable to use the `JavaScriptInterface` to call methods from javascript to Android on dynamic content.

Any solution to this problem?